# How to test too many Required and Relational Items in APXC

Tags: apex

I try to test my method, which get Id from one object.

the object has about 10 required fields, and 5 of them are relational.

I searched and found that I must make test data each of each,

get Id using soql, and set in order to test such object.

Like this,

```
Opportunity o = new Opportunity(
               Name = 'testing',
       );
         insert o;
Opportunity opty = [Select Id from Oportunity where Name = 'testing' Limit 1];
```

(from https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F0000000AzAaIAK)

I want to make test more easily, but don't want to use (SeeAllData=true).

Comment: If the related records are required, then you have no choice - your test method must create those related records first, then you can create the main record and link to those related records so that your test can proceed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You absolutely do not have to query if you only need the ID of a record. When you use the `insert` statement, the ID will be filled automatically. This is only a case with ID, not other fields though.

So you can simply do something like this:

```
Opportunity opp = new Opportunity(Name = 'Test');
insert opp;
My_custom_object__c mco = new My_custom_object__c(Name = 'Test', Opportunity__c = opp.Id);
insert mco;
```

Comment: It's good news for me. Thanks a lot!